# How can I create a security group if none is specified in a parameter in a cloudformation script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a parameter for security group:

```
"Parameters" : {
 "SecurityGroup" : {
   "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 Security Group ",
   "Type" : "String",
   "Default" : "default", 
   "MinLength": "1",
   "MaxLength": "64",
   "AllowedPattern" : "[-_ a-zA-Z0-9]*",
   "ConstraintDescription" : "can contain only alphanumeric characters, spaces, dashes and underscores."
  },
},
```

But rather than use the default, if no parameter is specified I'd like to create one.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were likely added after this question was asked, but for anyone that comes across this now, this can be done with [Conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) in CloudFormation.

So if we start with your Parameters declaration

```
"Parameters" : {
 "SecurityGroup" : {
   "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 Security Group ",
   "Type" : "String",
   "Default" : "default", 
   "MinLength": "1",
   "MaxLength": "64",
   "AllowedPattern" : "[-_ a-zA-Z0-9]*",
   "ConstraintDescription" : "can contain only alphanumeric characters, spaces, dashes and underscores."
  },
},
```

We could add a `Conditions` declaration, with a condition `ShouldCreateSecurityGroup`

```
"Conditions" : {
  "ShouldCreateSecurityGroup" : {"Fn::Equals" : [{"Ref" : "SecurityGroup"}, "default"]}
},
```

This condition can now be used to tell CloudFormation whether to create a security group:

```
"Resources": {
  "NewSecurityGroup": {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
    "Condition" : "ShouldCreateSecurityGroup" 
    "Properties" : {
       "SecurityGroupEgress" : [ Security Group Rule, ... ],
       "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ Security Group Rule, ... ],
    }
  }
}
```

Then when you go to reference the value in this, you can use the [Fn::If](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) Conditional function to say whether you want to use the value from the `SecurityGroup` parameter or the `NewSecurityGroup` Resource. For example, for passing the value into the `SecurityGroups` parameter of an EC2 instance, we could use `{"Fn::If}` like:

```
"Server": {
  {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties" : {
        ...
      "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Fn::If": ["ShouldCreateSecurityGroup", {"Ref": "NewSecurityGroup"}, {"Ref": "SecurityGroup"}]} ],
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No - Cloud Formation is a declarative language, so there's no "if/else" unfortunately.

You can't even do it by creating your own one and then passing in a "Ref" to the parameters as the parameter part is parsed and evaluated prior to script execution.

You could possibly do something with nested cloud formation script, but I haven't played with that enough to work out whether it's possible.  So for me - you'd have one script, that takes a parameter.  If the parameter is supplied, it passes that directly through to the second cloud formation, but if it isn't supplied, the first cloud formation is executed and returns the name of a newly created security group, and that is passed into the second cloud formation.

Comment: BTW, as of Nov 2013, CFN now supports conditionals: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html